# Split directories on python

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to split my working directory to get the base path of the script to be able to access a configuration file.
For example the directory I'm working is: C:\Users\testUser\PycharmProjects\my_script\script\bin
The directory I need is: C:\Users\testUser\PycharmProjects\my_script
So first I use `os.getcwd()` to get the path. --> C:\Users\testUser\PycharmProjects\my_script\script\bin
Then I apply `os.path.dirname(path)` this will return the directory name. --> C:\Users\testUser\PycharmProjects\my_script\script
Finally, I used `my_path, stuff = os.path.split(the_dirname)` this will give me the directory I need --> C:\Users\testUser\PycharmProjects\my_script
I would like to know if there is any better to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it is fine, but if you want to just get the parent directory of the current directory you are in, you can use `os.pardir`.

For example, on my machine (Mac OS) (note my current working directory was `/User/headless/Pictures/wallpapers`):

```
>>> import os
>>> current_path = os.getcwd()
>>> os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_path, os.pardir))
'/Users/headless/Pictures'
>>> os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_path, os.pardir)), os.pardir))
'/Users/headless'
```

Basically, all I did was ask for the parent directory. Then ask for the parent directory of the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a package in your diretory and go back to the root using: __PATH__.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages

Or

os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))